# bash script with network request in pure lsb environment

Tags: linux, networking, shell-script, standard

From what I can understand of LSB documentation, neither wget or netcat are standard tools always available in an LSB environment.

Is there some other way to make a http request without being dependent on anything else than LSB?
What would be the most safe tool to be dependent on if I want to make it as simple as possible for users of my tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the LSB includes both Perl and Python...Python, at least, includes http tools in the standard library.  I didn't investigate to see if the LSB mandates libwww-perl.

If you don't want to write anything yourself and you're happy with output to `stdout`, you can do this:

```
python -murllib http://example.com/
```

And if you're feeling really motivated, you can [write a simple http client in bash](http://web.archive.org/web/20120818034606/http://shudder.daemonette.org:80/source/BashNP-Guide.txt).

Comment: RedHat and its clones use python for the package-management - good hint.

Comment: If you have `libwww-perl` installed then you can also type `GET http://foo.com` . There are also options for POST and HEAD.

Comment: ...hence my question about whether or not the LSB mandates libwww-perl.

Comment: Actually I don't see nor python nor perl in lsb spec commands list ( http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/command.html ) or even in whole spec ( http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/book1.html ). Can you please show me the place where lsb incudes both perl and python?

Comment: I was looking at [this page](http://www.linuxbase.org/navigator/browse/command.php), but it was a quick look...

Comment: LSB-python doesn't include urrlib. See `./opt/lsb/share/appchk/lsb-python-modules.list` in `lsb-appchk-python`

Comment: Ooo, bummer.  The options get slimmer and slimmer.

Comment: Also, for those following along at home, I wasn't really serious with that bit about `bash`...

Comment: Actually, the pointer to the bash tutorial is why I accept this as answer; bash must be more commonly available than both wget and curl.. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

LSB is just Linux - and that might be an embedded device with not network at all. So there is no need to define HTTP in LSB.

Apart from that `wget` should be pretty standard in most distributions (e.g. SuSE uses wget in SuSEregister). Another tool might be `curl` - but you can not depend on these tools being available.

So if you want to use it - build a proper package and define a dependency (required: wget).

I see no other way for this.

Comment: Indeed. Then again the LSB includes `sendmail` and `lp`. But I don't think it includes any way to do HTTP.